# Cannot upload document via Telegram bot API

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I'm using `NestJS`, there is `axios` module inside it. I read that Telegram accepts only `multipart/form-data` for files, so I use `form-data` package. I have only 400 errors, that don't represent anything.
I don't want to use packages like `telegraf` (it's awesome, I know) for this simple usecase.

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
};

const file = await readFile(path);

const body = new FormData();
body.append('chat_id', this.chatId.toString());
body.append('document', file, { filename: 'document.pdf' });

try {
  const res = await firstValueFrom(this.http.post(`${this.tgURL}/sendDocument`, body, config));
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Telegram needs boundary in header.
So:

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${body.getBoundary()}` },
};
```